# How to get around EIP-170?

Tags: contract-deployment, eip170

I'm coding a contract that grew so much it is sizing bigger than the limit on [EIP-170](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/170).

I already replaced everything I could on inheritance and instanciation of other contracts with interfaces in the contract I want to deploy and even so it's still too big.

Is there any way to get around this problem?

More: I downloaded the [TrueUSD](https://github.com/trusttoken/trueUSD) code from GitHub and tried to deploy it on a Remix environment and it is also stumbling in the same problem. I suppose the same code was deployed in the mainnet in the past (as this token is being vastly traded for some time until now). Is it possible? How did they deploy it?

Comment: Try setting the ganache limit to the same as the mainnet using `-l 8000000`. From what I recall it is lower by default.